# How to read all the Realm objects which have permission

Tags: android, realm

I am developing a shared shopping list application where an user can share his/her list with the family members. I am using Realm Object Server as a database to store all the lists and users. The path for each list is like `/~/listName` where ~ is userid. I succeeded to give read/write permission to one user from another user. But now I am tackling to read all the lists which have permission. I know that I can get all the permission for current user with `PermissionManager.getPermission()` method, and then iterate the returned `RealmList<Permission>` and get paths. I used to use the following code to read the list created by current user.

```
SyncConfiguration config = SyncUser.current()
                .createConfiguration(listUrl)
                .fullSynchronization()
                .initialData(realm -> {
                    List list = new List();
                    String userId = SyncUser.current().getIdentity();
                    list.setOwner(userId);
                    realm.insert(list);
                })
                .waitForInitialRemoteData(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                .build();
```

But with this code I can only read one list which is stored in **listUrl**. What is proper way to read all the paths which have permission.